# glibc-2.14 compatibility

Tags: rhel, python, glibc

I'm developing an python application for my company on a RHEL 7.4, development environment. In my prod env, I'm running a RHEL 6.8 (soon to be upgraded). The problem is that I ran my application on testing env without problems, but on prod I'm facing various problems due to package versions. I've upgraded most of them, but now I have to install glibc-2.14. I've downloaded the package from the oficial repository, created a new build, ran `make` and waited several minutes for it to finish. My question is: is there any problem on installing that glibc on prod? I mean, could that "break" the OS on some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, upgrading the C library is a risky endeavour and could break the system, possibly in non-obvious ways. [*Upgrading the GNU C library within Red Hat Enterprise Linux*](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/17/upgrading-the-gnu-c-library-within-red-hat-enterprise-linux/) goes into details. You might run into issues with support too.

If the RHEL 6 system is soon to be upgraded to RHEL 7, your best bet might be to wait for that. As [Philip Couling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20140/philip-couling) [says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519958/glibc-2-14-compatibility/519961?noredirect=1#comment960847_519961), if your development and production environments don’t match, you’re [testing in production](https://twitter.com/stahnma/status/634849376343429120) anyway. Alternatively, you could look at [the Developer Toolset](https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/overview/) which will allow you to build and run compatible programs for RHEL 6 and 7, with newer versions of GCC and the C library.

Comment: I see. So I might as well just wait for the upgrade. I'll run the application on a remote server and send only the output to the prod server.

Comment: @VictorCamilo I'd agree with that option.  If your DEV and TST environments don't match PRD, you are effectively testing in PRD.  That's a really bad idea *always*.

Comment: Excellent point @Philip; “[Everybody has a testing environment. Some people are lucky enough enough to have a totally separate environment to run production in.](https://twitter.com/stahnma/status/634849376343429120)”